# Change size of <h1> tag when responsive Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid, bootstrap-4

Is there any way to change the text size of `<h1>` tag when it goes on extra small or small screen size?

Because `<h1>` has its own default size which is normal for medium size but very large for small and extra small.

I want to change that size when it goes to small screen size or extra small screen size.

Comment: Yes, you can do it by writing your own code. Create file `style.css` write media rule and add this file just after `bootstrap` lib.

Comment: can you provide me any link of media rule?

Comment: See this link https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom .css file (for example: site.css) and then use `@media` to create different behavior on different screen size. To override the `h1` class in bootstrap, you have to include your custom css after the bootstrap. Below is the example of `h1` in `site.css`:

```
h1 {
  /* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
  font-size: 10px;

  /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

This is the `@media` rules which bootstrap currently use, the official docs can be seen in [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries).

Comment: I came to this thread looking for recommended sizes. Does anybody know of a cheat sheet of font sizes per screen size kind of dealy-bop?

Comment: http://typecast.com/blog/a-more-modern-scale-for-web-typography

This goes good with what you put...

Comment: This is invalid CSS. You can't nest rules like that currently.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a basic example that shows how you can write your own CSS rule while you are using bootstrap or any other design framework.

for media query visit this [CSS-trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
/* My rule */

   h1{
      font-size:12px;
   }
   
</style>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Here is the heading</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @Amir Robert this is just an example i suggest you should create a separate style file and write all your style there. For media See this link https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use Media Query for small screen size that will apply css for h1 only on the specified width.
For example, See below code. You can modify it according to your needs. This code will go inside your styles.css file.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)  {
      h1 {
          font-size: 18px;
      }
}
```

For more info on media queries, visit Css Tricks.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
h1{
@media screen 
and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
{ 

          font-size: 100px;


}
@media screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 700px) 
{ 

          font-size: 25px;


}
}
 </style>

    <h1>My big company!</h1>


</html>
```

i hope it will help..

Comment: and what if I want to change this in JS?

Comment: @PirateApp in my opinion Bootstrap has been created to enable CSS to do its magic (but in a more easy to understand and structured way) without resorting to JavaScript for layout purposes. JavaScript's abilities are limitless, so back to your question: in this case you could dynamically add a class to the H1 element to change its dimensions.