# How can I change the size of the font in Bootstrap 4 with just CSS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, font-size

I just switch over to Bootstrap 4 from 3, and I'm finding it impossible to change the font size of any of the elements: h1, p, and even span.

> **UPDATE:** I want to change the size depending on the size of the screen. So using Media Queries.

I would like to thank @ZimSystem for how to change the size, but how can I change it depending on the media queries for different screen sizes?

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsa8d51x/)

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) {  h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }}

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
  }}

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { h1 {
    font-size: 150px;
  } }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
h1 {
    font-size: 200px;
  }

 }
```

My HTML:

```
<img class="img-responsive mx-auto d-block" src="./assets/brand/cmm.png" />

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
<h1><strong>This is sample title</strong></h1>
<h2 class="text-white">South Florida's Community of Creatives Come together</h2>
</div>

</div>
```

That doesn't seem to be working either.

**So am I missing something? Or is it impossible to change the font-size or make it responsive(depending on the screen size) in Bootstrap 4 with only CSS?**

Comment: @storaged, it's not a duplicate as it appears OP doesn't want to change **$font-base-size**, but only the size of some `h1` elements. ChosenJuan, when `!important` doesn't have any effect, either your CSS is not loaded/applying, or it's invalid/invalidated by some previous error in the file, or you're using the wrong selector. Triple check and use a different, more visible attribute, such as `border` or `background-color` to test it out. Keep in mind Bootstrap does not use `!important` for `font-size`, therefore `!important ` should apply. Which doesn't mean you should use it.

Comment: @storaged, the title of the question is admittedly misleading, therefore wrong, as a lot of users will come here looking for the answer to the other question. I wouldn't delete the duplication comment if I were you. Will prove useful for a lot of future users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how/where you're changing it. It should work fine. Make sure the custom CSS you're adding follows the `bootstrap.css`, and you shouldn't need to use `!important`

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/R9dGnr6AXn

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just updated my fiddle. Can you show me how to use media queries to get the same results depending on the screen size?

Comment: Take a look at other questions for media queries and responsive text (eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343195/change-size-of-h1-tag-when-responsive-bootstrap/45343362). It's basically a matter of wrapping the CSS in a media query for whatever screen sizes you want.

Comment: Can you demonstrate it using my fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/xsa8d51x/ It doen't seem to work with media queries.

Comment: Don't use // for comments in CSS. It's breaking the media queries. Updated codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/R9dGnr6AXn

Comment: Wow! Thank you for pointing that out! I completely overlooked the commenting syntax. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing vw instead of px. With my experience, px doesn't work well with font.

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) {  h1 {
     font-size: 30vw;
   }}

 // Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
 @media (min-width: 768px) { h1 {
     font-size: 100vw;
   }}

 // Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
 @media (min-width: 992px) { h1 {
     font-size: 150vw;
   } }

 // Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
 @media (min-width: 1200px) { 
 h1 {
     font-size: 200vw;
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extend bootstrap css and make the necesary changes or override the selector of your concern. No need to add !important.